# In DBSCAN, how to determine border points?

Tags: machine-learning, dbscan

In DBSCAN, the core points is defined as having more than MinPts within Eps.

So if MinPts = 4, a points with total 5 points in Eps is definitely a core point. 
How about a point with 4 points (including itself) in Eps? Is it a core point, or a border point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Border points are points that are (in DBSCAN) **part of a cluster, but not dense themselves** (i.e. every cluster member that is *not* a core point).

In the followup algorithm HDBSCAN, the concept of border points was discarded.

> Campello, R. J. G. B.; Moulavi, D.; **Sander, J**. (2013).
>   **Density-Based Clustering Based on Hierarchical Density Estimates.**
>   Proceedings of the 17th Pacific-Asia Conference on Knowledge Discovery in Databases, PAKDD 2013. Lecture Notes in Computer Science 7819. p. 160.
>   doi:10.1007/978-3-642-37456-2_14

which states:

> Our new definitions are more consistent with a statistical interpretation of clusters as connected components of a level set of a density  [...] border objects do not technically belong to the level set (their estimated density is below the threshold).

Comment: What if `minPts = 1` ? Every point is core point?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just re-read the original paper and Definition 1 makes it look like the core point belongs to its own eps neighborhood. So if minPts is 4, then a point needs at least 3 others in its eps neighborhood.

Notice in Definition 1 that they say NEps(p) = {q ∈D | dist(p,q) ≤ Eps}. If the point were excluded from its eps neighborhood, then it would have said NEps(p) = {q ∈D | dist(p,q) ≤ Eps and p != q}. Where != is "not equal to".

This is also reinforced by the authors of DBSCAN in their OPTICS paper in Figure 4. http://fogo.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/OPTICS.pdf

So I think the SciKit interpretation is correct and the Wikipedia illustration is misleading in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on the implementation. The best way is to just play with the implementation yourself.

In the original DBSCAN<sup>1</sup>  paper, core point condition is given as N_Eps>=MinPts, where N_Eps is the Epsilon neighborhood of a certain data point, which is excluded from its own N_Eps.

Following your example, if MinPts = 4 and N_Eps = 3 (or 4 including itself as you say), then they don't form a cluster according to the original paper. On the other hand, the scikit-learn<sup>2</sup> implementation of DBSCAN works otherwise, meaning it counts the point itself for forming a group. So for MinPts=4, four points are needed in total to form a cluster.

[1] Ester, Martin; Kriegel, Hans-Peter; Sander, Jörg; Xu, Xiaowei (1996). "A density-based algorithm for discovering clusters in large spatial databases with noise."

[2] http://scikit-learn.org